# Why does malloc give different addresses on "b" and "b[0]"?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I had this example at class, whitout a proper explaination:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    const int dim = 10;
    int i, a[dim], *b;
    b = (int *)malloc(dim*sizeof(int));
    printf("\n Address of a : %x", &a);
    printf("\n Address of a[0]: %x", &a[0]);
    printf("\n Dimension of a : %d bytes", sizeof(a));
    printf("\n Address of b : %x", &b);
    printf("\n Address of b[0]: %x", &b[0]);
    printf("\n Dimension of b : %d bytes", sizeof(b));
    free(b);//free allocated memory
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain this behavior of malloc, that b is different from b[0]?

```
Address of a : ffffcb90
Address of a[0]: ffffcb90
Dimension of a : 40 bytes
Address of b : ffffcbc0
Address of b[0]: 103a0
Dimension of b : 8 bytes
```

Comment: `printf("\n Address of b : %x", &b);` would need to be `printf("\n Address of b : %x", b);` without the `&`. As it was you are asking where the pointer resides, not its value. BTW please use `%p` format for pointers, and cast the argument as `(void*)b`.

Comment: Because the address of b is different than the address its content points to.

Comment: The result that `&a` points to the same place as `&a[0]` arises from the fact that `a` is an array.  `b` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Because pointers are not arrays.

Comment: "explain this behavior of malloc, that b is different from b[0]?" --> Posting your thoughts would clarify your issue.  What did you expect?

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, all of the advice was precious

Comment: The "%x" is for integers not pointers, use "%p" for pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` is a local variable, and resides on the stack. Its value is interpreted as a pointer.
When malloc allocates memory on (the heap)you assign that address to `b` so now `b` is a pointer (which is still stored in the same place, on the stack), and points to an array on the heap.

`b[0]` is the first element in that array.

In contrast, `a` is an array fully allocated locally, so it resides on the stack completely - that makes `a` the array itself, so `a[0]` is the same. Try to assign the malloc return value to `a` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

- `&b` is *the address of the variable* named `b`. That variable happens to point to some array, but that's irrelevant here.
- `&b[0]` is *the address of the first element of the array pointed to* by `b`. In other words, it is the same as `b + 0`, so in this case it's the value of `b`.